# Adding odata proxy in sencha architect

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, odata, sencha-architect

Can anybody help me how to add  odata proxy in Sencha architect in model proxy.
 In the list i can only see [image]. How can i add a Odata proxy for model from Sencha architect ?

[Demo from SAP](http://scn.sap.com/community/mobile/blog/2012/12/21/building-sap-mobile-apps-with-sencha-touch--part-2)

I cant event edit my proxy setting from Sencha architect.

Comment: You can import custom components if you have a `.xdc` file. It looks like they use `ajax` proxy